# Grid960 SharePoint Page Layout

Tags: css, sharepoint, page-layout

My master page are using the Grid960 CSS framework. But I am not sure that my page layout is using the CSS framework correctly.

I got the nasty vertical and horizontal scroll bars. How can I get rid of the nasty vertical and horizontal scroll bars?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [css property `overflow: hidden;`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/overflow) to remove both scrollbars

or you can target each specifically:

- `overlow-x: hidden;`
- `overflow-y: hidden;`

Answer (score 1):

Here are my suggestions:

1. I would suggest to use IEDeveloperToolBar or Fiddler and make sure all css referenced are linked properly and not showing 404.
2. Reference shraepoint related css first and then reference 960 grid css in exact order in which they are referenced in example html.

If you need more help, post some example url so that it can be reviewed.